# Multilevel inheritance, generic, raw type

Tags: java

I need a solution, is my code structure correct, or is it a bad code structure?
The main problem is that compiler swears at the raw type.

1. Is this code structure bad? Why? Is it correct?

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface EntityRepository<E, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<E, ID> {
}
    
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CatalogEntityRepository<C extends Catalog.Main, E extends CatalogEntity, ID extends Serializable>
        extends EntityRepository<E, ID>, Catalog.Able<C> {
}
    
@Repository
public interface OrganizationEntityRepository extends CatalogEntityRepository<OrganizationCatalog, OrganizationEntity, Long> {
    @Override
    default OrganizationCatalog getCatalog() {
        return Context.getApplicationContext().getBean(OrganizationCatalog.class);
    }
}
```

2. Is this code structure bad? Why? Is it correct?

```
// Here I have some context class (CatalogEntityRepositoryContextImpl) that can find the repository which I need.

public interface EntityRepositoryContext<R extends EntityRepository> {
    List<R> getAll();

    Optional<R> find(String parentAlias);

    default R get(String parentAlias) {
        return find(parentAlias).orElseThrow(() -> {
            throw new NoSuchEntityRepositoryException(parentAlias);
        });
    }

}

public interface CatalogEntityRepositoryContext<R extends CatalogEntityRepository>
        extends EntityRepositoryContext<R> {
    @Override
    default Optional<R> find(String catalogAlias) {
        return getAll().stream()
                .filter(it -> Objects.equals(it.getCatalog().getAlias(), catalogAlias))
                .findFirst();
    }

    @Override
    default R get(String catalogAlias) {
        return find(catalogAlias).orElseThrow(() -> {
            throw new NoSuchCatalogEntityRepositoryException(catalogAlias);
        });
    }
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CatalogEntityRepositoryContextImpl
        implements CatalogEntityRepositoryContext<CatalogEntityRepository> {

    @Getter
    private final List<CatalogEntityRepository> all;

}
```

3. And my main problem with raw type is: the code works, but I need confirmation from the guru that this code is not too bad, or give me some useful solutions, please.
   I know raw type is bad practice. But I can't figure out how I can fix this in my situation.

```
public interface CatalogEntityService<C extends Catalog.Main, DS extends CatalogEntityDto.Single, DL extends CatalogEntityDto.Listable>
        extends EntityService<DS, DL>, Catalog.Able<C> {

    private CatalogEntityRepository getRepository() {
        CatalogEntityRepositoryContextImpl repositoryContext = Context.getCatalogEntityRepositoryContext();
        return repositoryContext.get(getCatalog().getAlias());
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    default Long create(DS dto) {
        var repository = getRepository();
        var mapper = getMapper();
        var entity = mapper.mapToEntity(dto);
        var savedEntity = repository.save(entity); // HERE IS THE RAW TYPE! "Unchecked call to 'save(S)' as a member of raw type 'app.unibas.core.catalog.repository.CatalogEntityRepository'"
        return (Long) savedEntity.getId();
    }

}
```

Comment: What error do you get, and where, when you try to make it not raw?

Comment: Actually, I don't get error. I just want to get an expert's solution- is my code structure correct or it's bad code. Because I'm a newcomer java-developer and I have not enough experience.

Comment: Avoid raw types and classes as much as possible, especially if you are new to java.